# Font Awseome icons displaying as empty box

Tags: font-awesome

This has been asked before, but the answer to that was that OP was missing an `.fa` class...

I copied this instagram icon from fontawesome.com:

```
<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
```

At first I tried to use bootstrapcdn:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

This did not work so I removed this from `<head>` and gave fontawesome my email and they emailed me my own cdn, I put this at the bottom of `<body>`:

```
<body>
<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fb0e3670d6.js"></script>
</body>
```

This didn't work either, still an empty box. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing font awesome version 4.7, so you should use the config from that version of the website, i.e. [fa-instagram](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/instagram).

Therefore to show the instagram icon, you need to change your html to:

```
<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```